# How to dynamically change the text in the title of the Website

Tags: javascript, html, title

A few years back I saw a website that had a really intresting title,
When you opened the site the title of the site displayed a large amount of 1's and 0's which were changing rapidly, sort of like the Matrix effect and eventually it trimed and slowed out to the orignal website title.

Any Ideas on how I could re-create such an effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.javascriptsource.com/page-details/dynamic-title.html

this obviously won't give you the 1's and 0's effect you want, but it does show you how to change the title of your website. as for the "matrix effect" you wanted you can just write a function to start with a random string of 1's and 0's and keep randomly changing it until the 10th or whatever iteration where you insert the first actual letter, and then insert the second letter on the 12th, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the document title is easy:

```
document.title = '1001010';
```

Combine that with an interval and you can create a "animation"....

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.title = 'new title' to change the title with javascript.

I guess the website you are talking about used some document.title = 'new title' inside loops with intervals to do what you described.

Comment: Yes, i think that would do the trick , but could you please write a short example with the loops and the intervals, as Im unsure exactly how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

If its not simply a change in text. What your talking about sounds like an animated image or .gif where it was an animated background image.

Also with the latest IE10 and DirectWrite you are able to manually create a text/font and choose to animate and manipulate your text, take a look at this link: [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)